# UNC path not working with $

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a unc path like this:

```
var path =@"\\\\Server001\R$\XYZ";
```

When I use Directory.Exists(path) I am always getting false but the path does exists in the system.
The actual result should be true.I am getting true if I give path =@"\\Server001\XYZ", but when the path contains R$ its not working. Any ideas?

Comment: are you missing a \ at the beginning? `var path =@"\\Server001\R$\XYZ";`

Answer (score 1):

Probably a security issue. If you use a default share, the required user to be logged on might differ from the one using the normal share.

Try using `\\Server001\R$\XYZ`in your explorer. If you have to put in credentials, it was that.

`Directory.Exists(Path)` returns false if there are insufficient rights to access.